# Text following mouse cursor when CTRL key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to detect when user press the `CTRL` key when over the red div box. When this is the case, I need to inject text `Ctrl key pressed` just beside the mouse. This text must follow the mouse cursor as long as `CTRL` key is pressed. If mouse leaves the red div box, the text must be hided. Furthermore use can press the `ctrl` key inside the red box **without moving the mouse** and the text must also be displayed (and hided when `ctrl` key released).

1st version HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

1st version JAVASCRIPT code:

```
    var mousePosition;
    $('#container').append('<p id="besideMouse">Ctrl key pressed</p>');
    $('#box').mousemove(function (e) {
        mousePosition = { top: e.pageY + 10, left: e.pageX + 10 };
    });
    $("#box").hover(function (e) {

        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey) $('#besideMouse').show().offset(mousePosition);
        });
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (!e.ctrlKey) $('#besideMouse').hide();
        });
    }, function (e) {
        $(document).unbind("keydown");
        $('#besideMouse').hide();
    });
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/o7Lbc91o/2/

It is compatible Google Chrome & Internet Explorer.

Please note for testing Inside the jsfiddle, first click inside the `Result` area otherwise it don't works.

It works but NOW I need to use `live` event handlers for some reasons not visible Inside this basic example. The reason (in short) is I have a grid which is dynamic and when sorted it don't work anymore so I need this code to refactorised.

So I try to refactor see 2nd version here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbdzxpk7/1/

**But the problem (GOOGLE CHROME ONLY) with this 2nd version**: when my mouse cursor is inside the red box (and without moving the cursor) when `ctrl` key is pressed the text is no more displayed. It works with IE but no more with GC.

Any idea how to solve this 2nd version ?

PS: maybe my code is not very efficient, so don't hesitate to adapt it if necessary

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tbdzxpk7/5/

Comment: Thank you very interesting. One question: do you know a way of avoiding clicking first inside the area?

Comment: hah)) its only need on **jsfiddle**. because script running in **another frame** and can't capture all events.